# Could not get unknown property 'PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION'

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, ionic2, google-play-services

i am getting **Could not get unknown property 'PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION'** error in ionic build after installing cordova-plugin-googlemaps in my ionic 3 app. if i remove this plugin then no error is showing in build. after adding this plugin again error is showing.

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable
>   API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE"

i replaced YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE with the key i got from google.

same way i added in another app there it was working. here its not working

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/could-not-get-unknown-property-google-play-services-version/114176/6

Comment: i tried this also after adding version i am getting this error - cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions

Answer (score 10):

In \platforms\android\project.properties, replace PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION by “+” only

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
```

Another way: install cordova plugin to create version automatically

```
cordova plugin add cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build your app with PhoneGap build, you need to specify the `phonegap-version` because that is a bug of PhoneGap build.

```
<widget ...>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="^2.2.3">
    <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="(api key)" />
    <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="(api key)" />
    <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="11.8.0" />
    <variable name="LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION" value="Show your location on the map" />
    <variable name="LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Trace your location on the map" />
  </plugin>

  <!--
    You need to specify cli-7.1.0 or greater version.
    https://build.phonegap.com/current-support
  -->
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />
</widget>
```

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/tree/3ee006140b4c83d59a6545aa5218fbcdb962cb9b#phonegap-build-settings

Comment: i am not using phonegap build, now i solved this issue by using older version of cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Comment: I found the final answer. Your cordova is old. You need to update the cordova-cli 7.1.0 or over

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I started with this approach: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/2039

I changed the project.properties and build.gradle in the platforms android folder. Replaced the $PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION variable with 11.8.0+ and removed the PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION parameter from config.xml

After this I checked for the latest update for google-play-services in the new SDK manager in Android Studio.

Maybe the last step is enough, but this were the steps I took.

**EDIT:**

A **quick solution** can be adding the line maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } to your build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I haven't problem without this, but I added your suggestion into the plugin code. https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/commit/d6a64025a3fd59a21f8ab2e695420b42c0f8c91a